# importing from venv folder with same file name

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm using a redis library in python with virtualenv.

I have a file namely `redis.py` which has the following import;

```
import redis

class RedisExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, config):
        print redis

class Redis(Facade):
    pass
```

However, it seems that it performs a self import even when venv folder is activated.
I need to make redis.py import redis from venv folder which has the redis library installed by pip **without changing any names in here**.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Btw, your requirement is rather uncommon and what I show here is sort of hack. It would be better if
you manage renaming your python script/module to something more reasonable.

By default, Python sets up importing from number of different paths, one of them being current one.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sys.path
['',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/bin',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/javl/.ipython']
```

As you see, the very first item is "". This means "this directory". Remove it:

```
>>> os.sys.path.remove("")
>>> os.sys.path
['/home/javl/Envs/so/bin',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/javl/Envs/so/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/javl/.ipython']
>>> import redis
```

If we want to put thing back into original order, we can do it by:

```
>>> os.sys.path.insert(0, "")
```

You shall put this modification into your `redis.py`

```
os.sys.path.remove("")
import redis
os.sys.path.insert(0, "")

class RedisExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, config):
        print redis

class Redis(Facade):
    pass
```

Comment: Follow the import with `os.sys.path.insert(0, "")` to put it back.

Comment: thanks for the help, I think it'll be better if I change the module name

Comment: @erbridge Good, inserted.

Comment: @aacanakin Very good decision to change the name. Having python file with conflicting name is rather common source of problems - now you will know, what to check, if such problems do happen. Personally, manipulating `os.sys.path` is something, what I try to avoid as much as possible. It is a trick, and trick can look simple but can be sometime very tricky.